# how to grep external txt file in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, hosting, cat

I would like to run a script that can be access in other terminals other then my own. like bash <(curl -s http://domain.com/scripts/hello.sh) but I need this script to grep a txt file that is also located on that server for example domain.com/scripts/stuff.txt. What would be the best method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a text file, and pipe it into grep:

`curl http://domain.com/scripts/stuff.txt | grep foo`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
curl -s http://domain.com/scripts/stuff.txt | grep "$Hi"
```

You can redirect the output to a local text file, like so:

```
curl -s http://domain.com/scripts/stuff.txt | grep "$Hi" > stuff_that_starts_with_hi.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `wget`

```
wget -qO - http://domain.com/scripts/stuff.txt | grep dat
```